# Google maps integrated to openlayers are not visible in firefox and internet explorer

Tags: firefox, google-maps-api-3, openlayers

I integrated google maps as a base layer (wms layer) with openlayers. The system was working properly and all the browsers were displaying the base layer google map properly.

Then I updated firefox. Now the firefox has stopped showing the google maps (wfs layers). But it still show the wfs features.

I tried it in google chorme and internet explorer also (newest versions). Google chrome displays everything properly. But the internet explorer has the same problem.

How could I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

New versions of IE and Firefox are not supporting map outputs if you are using local file paths in your codes. Try using url of the files you want to access or just put all your files into one folder and then use in ie or firefox. That may solve it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, both of the browsers display features. I cannot see only the base layer google map (The base layer is displayed as a gray background). Also, I am not using any local file paths in my code.